# dplyr::slice_max - Hand over order_by as calculated string

Tags: r, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

I want to hand over the name of a variable as a string to the `order_by` argument of `dplyr::slice_max()`, but I'm getting weird results. Using the `iris` data here.

```
library(dplyr)

lastcol <- first(colnames(iris))
```

My expected result would be a df/tibble of 5 rows, which works while using the actual column name.

```
i <- iris %>% 
  slice_max(n = 5, order_by = Sepal.Length)
```

But when handing over the column name, I'm either getting unexpected results or errors.

```
# unexpected result: one row
i <- iris %>% 
  slice_max(n = 5, order_by = lastcol)

# unexpected result: one row
i <- iris %>% 
  slice_max(n = 5, order_by = !!lastcol)

# Error: `:=` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument
i <- iris %>% 
  slice_max(n = 5, order_by := .data[[lastcol]])
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what `newstrdelcol` is. But if you want to use what you have defined in `lastcol` you can do it with `get(lastcol)` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

lastcol <- first(colnames(iris))

iris %>% 
  slice_max(n = 5, order_by = get(lastcol))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 1          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
#> 2          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
#> 3          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
#> 4          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
#> 5          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
```

Comment: My bad, I hadn't replaced a variable there. Yes, I wanted to use `lastcol`. 
How does `get()` fit into the overall NSE concept? Is there a equivalent in the tidyverse?

Comment: @`Timm S`. I am sorry, but I can't tell you, how it fits into NSE. The documentation says _get() function is used to return an object with the name specified as argument to the function_

Answer (score 1):

In the new version, we can also use `pick`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
   slice_max(n = 5, order_by = pick(all_of(lastcol)))
```

-output

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
2          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
3          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
4          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
5          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
```